# Terraform - How to iterate through a list and supply the value to a list(map(string)?

Tags: terraform

So, I have a list of items such as

```
public_subnet_ip = flatten(module.master_nodes.*.public_ip)
```

Which contain a list of IPs of my master nodes. The output of the variable is something like this

```
public_subnet_ip = ["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2", "10.0.0.3"]
```

Now, I have a resource with these arguments.

```
resource "some_resource" "this" {
       name = var.name
       master_nodes = [
           {
              address = "an-ip-address"
           },
       ]
}
```

What I would like to do is to iterate through the `public_subnet_id` variable, pick each element, and fill in the `address` field in the resource.

I tried this and it created 3 separate master_nodes resources instead of a single master node resource which contains 3 nodes in it.

```
resource "some_resource" "this" {
       name = var.name
       count = length(var.public_subnet_ip)
       master_nodes = [
           {
              address = element(var.public_subnet_ip, count.index)
           },
          
       ]
}
```

This is what I'm having right now

```
resource "some_resource" "this" {
       name = var.name
       master_nodes = [
           {
              address = public_subnet_ip[0]
           },
           {
              address = public_subnet_ip[1]
           },
           {
              address = public_subnet_ip[2]
           },
          
       ]
}
```

Comment: What do you expect as a result? `master_nodes = [{address = "10.0.0.1"},{address = "10.0.0.2"},{address = "10.0.0.3"},]`?

Comment: "seems not to work" - is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any errors?

Comment: What I expect is that I will have a resource which is master_nodes that have 3 nodes (IP addresses) in it instead of 3 different master_nodes and with its own IPs.

Comment: @Marcin what seemed not to work is when I applied the above Terraform code, It created 3 separate master nodes, each of them having IP from the public_subnet_ip list.

Comment: Sadly its still not clear. What errors do you get? The lack of clarify is due to using `some_resource`. No one knows what it is, on one can check its documentation to verify correct values.